# How to add a DIV to select option using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My question is about java script, i want to put or add a div or button or input inside select tag using java script.

I using jquery.sumoselect plugin that make you multiple checkbox, but when i want to add some DIVs inside select tag is showing outside the list.

i want the div inside select element like this picture : https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xd6FX.jpg

this is my html code

```
<div class="select-box-style right">
                    <div class="your-list-title">Your Lists</div>

                    <select multiple="multiple" class="md_what_get right SlectBox">
                        <option selected value="electronics">Electronics</option>
                        <option value="games">Video Games</option>
                        <option value="books">Books</option>
                        <option value="others">Others</option>
                        <option value="others"><input type="text" name="lname"></option>
                    </select>
                    <div class="add-list-box">
                        <input type="text" class="input-add-list"/>
                        <label class="label-spcbtn-blue spr" >Add</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

and this how to call the plugin:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                    $(document).ready(function () {
                        $('.SlectBox').SumoSelect();
                    });
                </script>
```

thank you for helping!

....
**Update!**

see this link http://wenzhixin.net.cn/p/multiple-select/docs/

On The Filter1 you can see the input search inside select element, how can i do that?

Comment: You can only put `option` or `optgroup` tags within a `select`:  http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-select-element

Comment: If you're ever having difficulties getting HTML to show properly, start off by validating it: https://validator.w3.org/. As Rick said, the `select` tag cannot have `input` or `div` tags within them.

Comment: @RickHitchcock thank you for answer can you see the link Update you can see on the filter1 a input inside this list ccan you help me how can i do that?

Comment: Ahh, your updated question references **multiple-select**, which takes a `select` object and changes it into `div`s and `li`s, which *can* hold `input`s, etc.  I'm unfamiliar with that plugin, but someone else may be able to help you.

Comment: thank you @RickHitchcock if you know anyone may be able to help me share this question with hem thank you

Answer (score 1):

Neither SumoSelect or MultipleSelect (as is) supports the feature you are looking at. But, first, some clarification needed:

<select> boxes are a standard HTML tag, that accepts no other tags than <optgroup> or <option>. see here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select

SumoSelect and MultipleSelect are both Javascript plugins that “converts” real selects into custom built <div> tags, with javascript to handle the logic.
That said, you can either modify/extend those plugins to create the desired <div> or you can build your own “<select> into <div> converter”.

But, for the sake of simplicity, you could just create a <div> with all the desired functionality, using regular plain old checkboxes, and hiding/displaying the whole <div> according to your UX flow/needs.

Comment: @RodrigoBrancher can you help me please to write this code lika what i want on the image on my question?

Comment: @RodrigoBancher i'm beginner so i not sure for your answer or you can say i'm not understand your answer pleas write me the code if you can, and thank you soo much!

Comment: @RickHitchcock if you understand Rodrigo's answer can you help me to write the code pleas

Comment: @Machine:  Your post refers to two separate plug-ins:  SumoSelect (which is in your JavaScript code), and multiple-select (which is in your link).  I'm unfamiliar with either plug-in.  But if you narrow it down to one or the other, someone may be able to help you.

Comment: @RickHitchcock i use just one plugin is sumoselect i'm not use two plugins multiple-select is just example to show  you the div can add to select tag im using one plugin

Comment: Gotcha.  I don't know if SumoSelect can do everything that multiple-select does (or vice-versa).

Comment: @RickHitchcock the plugin create <div class="optWrapper multiple open"><ul class="options"> by using javascript file plugin this is the code O.optDiv = $('<div class="optWrapper">');

                    //$(".your-lists-style").append("<div>Your Lists</div>")
                    
                   

                    //branch for floating list in low res devices.
                    O.floatingList();

                    //Creating the markup for the available options
                    ul = $('<ul class="options">');
                    O.optDiv.append(ul);

Comment: @RodrigoBrancher see the plugin file you cansee the plugin create a div automaticlly how can i do that

Comment: forget about the plugins. write the div html code... the tool you are trying to use is not built for the need your are facing. think in steps: your firsr need is to display the user's lists. do this with simple checkboxes and labels. then you need a field and a button to collect new lists creations. just do an input and a button, with some javascript to collect and send this data to server. wrap it all on a div, and create a button/link/whatever to display and hide this div. pretty straight forward.